# JavaScript calling 3 function at one time

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I am calling 3 jQuery function in only click <kbd>ok</kbd> link.

Please tell me is this right or how I can do it.

Its not working properly:

```
<a href=# onClick="fill(\''.$result->pname.'\');fill1(\''.$result->person_name.'\');fill2(\''.$result->mobile.'\');">Click me</a>
```

Comment: yes offcourse i m doing in php

Comment: k its fine.. Are you getting blank page... Are you able to see the values of $result->pname etc in source code from browser...

Comment: Its not obvious that you were doing it in PHP it could well have been buggy jquery code. No need to be abrupt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know the result of it...

```
<?php echo "<a href=# onClick='fill(\"".$result->pname."\");fill1(\"".$result->person_name."\");fill2(\"".$result->mobile."\");'>Click me</a>"; ?>
```

Hope it helps...